# pandas groupby().size(), to excel line graph

Tags: python, excel, pandas, graph

```
random_df
```

| Line | Generation | SNP-1 | SNP-2 | SNP-3 | SNP-4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020A | A | A | A | A |
| B | 2020B | A | C | T | G |
| C | 2020C | A | C | T | G |
| D | 2020D | A | C | T | G |
| A | 2020A | A | A | A | A |

```
data = {'Line': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A'], 'Generation': ['2020A', '2020B', '2020C', '2020D', '2020A'],
        'SNP-1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 
        'SNP-2': ['A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A'],
        'SNP-3': ['A', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'A'],
        'SNP-4': ['A', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'A']
       }
random_df = pd.DataFrame(data)  

grp = random_df.set_index(["Line", "Generation"]).apply(tuple, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

hap_groups = random_df.groupby(["Line", "Generation", grp]).size()
```

How can I use this object to make a line graph for each group? In an ideal world it would be written into a spreadsheet, but if I can graph it in pandas that is great. Will figure out how to add to a spreadsheet later.

groupby().size() shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD3yd.jpg) and you can see there is 2 for 2020A

Comment: Hi, probably is impossible to graph this in a line plot because the x-axis (Line or generation) are not continuous, in the case that the `dataframe` contains data like 2020 2019 or more years, is logical to make a line graph. For this case an idea is a `bar plot`, but my question is, the values in the columns SNP-1 (2,3,4) are numbers?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by line graph for each group? Like what from `hap_groups` is represented on the x and y axis?

Comment: @Simon have a look at this edited image from excel. https://imgur.com/a/iqjxi87 the idea is that the groups will contain a range of values over time.

Comment: @kb9alpp Where did you get the x and y-axis numbers from? In your example, how is this red, blue, and green line represented by Line A? In other words, how does Line A from your graph represent `A 2020A (A, A, A, A) 2)`?

Comment: @gañañufla The values in the columns SNP-1 (2,3,4) are letters but, when grouped with the groupby().size(), there is a depiction of the number of times that group will show up for the generation. If feasible, I could list years along the x axis or just use a bar chart.

Comment: @Simon The x is the generation, and the y is the amount of times that the groupby().size() size shows up in the generation at that time. the graph is not directly related, meant to be used as a visual where the data is not the same as my provided example in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
df = (hap_groups
      .reset_index(name='count')
      .assign(generation=lambda d: d['Generation'].str.extract('^(\d+)').astype(int))
     )
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='generation', y='count', hue='Line', marker='o')
```

output (just 2 points here):

[image]

Comment: Have you had a chance to give it a try?